# Incomplete highlight in c++-mode with Emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, highlight, emacs23

I work with C++ in emacs, and it works perfect, except for a detail when highlighting the code. Whenever I write a function with more than one argument (sometimes, even with just one), it does not recognice the function as a function, for instance, in:

```
double Gamma(double x, double mean, double gamma){
  //some code
}
```

`Gamma` is not highlighted like a function, but as plain text, while in `#define square(x) x*x`, `square` is properly highlighted, as well in

```
complex<double> magphase2c(double mag, double phase){
// some code
}
```

where magphace2c is highlighted as a function.

The same behaviour occurs when I have, for instance,

```
TF1 *fitBWResult = new TF1("fitBWResult", BreitWigner, ResMassMin, ResMassMax, 3);
// versus
double Mass = 0.776132;
```

where `fitBWResult` is not recognized as a variable, but `Mass` is. This last problem only happens when I use pointers.

I'm using Emacs 23.4.1, I don't know the version of cc-mode, but I'm running an up to date installation of Debian testing (wheezy).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works fine for me. (Emacs 23.3.1 from repo, Ubuntu 12.04, mostly default settings). Maybe you can download a newer cc-mode? Also, are you sure it's in C++ mode and not C mode? (Probably is, but doesn't hurt to check)

Comment: I've double checked (well, almost a houndred times). The configuration is almost the default. I haven't tried with a newer cc-mode, thought. I think the second problem has to do with pointers, more than with a particular format. I cannot try it now, but I will try your suggestion with a newer cc-mode. Thanks!

Comment: I've finally came to an answer: noisecapella was right, the problem was the cc-mode version. Debian Wheezy came with 5.31.something, and the issue is fixed in the version 5.32.3 (the last in the project page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question shouldn't be left without an answer, and since I solved it thanks to the idea of user noisecapella, I post the solution I found:

Debian Wheezy, at the time, uses cc-mode 5.31.8 with Emacs 23.4.1, and **this** version of cc-mode is the one with the problem. The solution is install the newer version (maybe an old one may do the job, also) of the package, [from their homepage](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/index.php). Particularly, I solved the issue installing version 5.32.3, the newer at the time being.